# Shiny Dashboard change background color of slectInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a Shiny Dashabord with multiple selectInputs. Now I want to change the background color of the selectInput if a value outside of the default was clicked.

So here is a code snippet:

```
dbHeader <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Test",
  titleWidth = "400px"
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dbHeader,
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("filter_head")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    #some content
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$filter_head <- renderUI({
  column(
      12,
      selectInput("select_1", h3("Select1"),
        c(
          "Default", "A", "B",
          "C",
          "D"
        ), selected = "Default", selectize = FALSE, multiple = F)
      ),
 selectInput("select_2", h3("Select2"),
        c(
          "Default", "A", "B",
          "C",
          "D"
        ), selected = "Default", selectize = FALSE, multiple = F)
      )
)
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So if not default was selected at select_1, the background of select_1 should be red otherwise white. But only for the select_1 Input. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it. With an uiOutput and an if else statement.

I create a new uiOutput Element and uses the statement in the render Method:

```
uiOutput("style_select_1")      

output$style_select_1<- renderUI({
        if(is.null(input$select_1)){
          return()
        }
        else if(input$select_1!= 'Default'){
          return(tags$style("#select_1{background-color:red;color:white;}"))
        }
      })
```